# jQuery if hasClass does not work

Tags: html, css, toggle, jquery

I am struggling with checking if an element has a specific class and thus performing an action. I can manage to show an element (but not hide it), but as soon as I apply the IF statement, it does not work anymore.

Works:

```
function showmenu() {
  $('#sidebar-menu').removeClass('hidemenu');
  $('#sidebar-menu').addClass('showmenu');
}
```

Does not work:

```js
function showmenu() {
  if ($('#sidebar-menu').hasClass('hidemenu')) {
    $('#sidebar-menu').removeClass('hidemenu');
    $('#sidebar-menu').addClass('showmenu');
  }

  if ($('#sidebar-menu').hasClass('showmenu')) {
    $('#sidebar-menu').removeClass('showmenu');
    $('#sidebar-menu').addClass('hidemenu');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidemenu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.showmenu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:showmenu();">Open Menu</a>
```

Comment: you can use toggleclass its better

Comment: Or consider using vanilla JavaScript, as in `document.getElementById('sidebar-menu').classList.toggle('showmenu')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code comes from the conditions, you're not using `else` statement so the both condition will fire if your element has class ``` hidemenu``and the class will be changed two times, the first condition will add the class ```showmenu`and the second condition will remove it, so please add the`else` to your logic :

```
function showmenu() {
    if($('#sidebar-menu').hasClass('hidemenu')){
        $('#sidebar-menu').removeClass('hidemenu');
        $('#sidebar-menu').addClass('showmenu');
    } else if($('#sidebar-menu').hasClass('showmenu')){
        $('#sidebar-menu').removeClass('showmenu');
        $('#sidebar-menu').addClass('hidemenu');
    } // end if has class
} // end function
```

**NOTE :** The effecient way is to use `toggleClass()` :

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default action

    $('#sidebar-menu').toggleClass('hidemenu showmenu');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

Instead of using multiple classes, just assume that the hidden status is your default status of the menu. Then, all you need is to apply one class to actually toggle the menu.

Hope this will help you. :)

```js
function showMenu() {
  $('#menu').toggleClass('show');
}

$('a').on('click', function() {
  showMenu();
});
```

```css
#menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#menu.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="">Open Menu</a>

<div id="menu">HI, MENU HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your logic is because you have two separate `if` statements. The first one adds the `showmenu` class if it wasn't already on the element. The second then detects the class you just added is now on the element and removes it again. The net result is that nothing appears to happen.

To fix this either join the logic in to a single `if/else` statement, or better yet, use `toggleClass()`, like this:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#sidebar-menu').toggleClass('hidemenu showmenu');
});
```

```css
.hidemenu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.showmenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="">Open Menu</a>

<div id="sidebar-menu" class="hidemenu">
  Menu goes here...
</div>
```

Note the use of an unobtrusive event handler and also specifying only the `opacity` CSS property to animate instead of supplying `all`.

Answer (score 1):

much cleaner code with `toggleClass`

```js
$('button').mouseover(function() {
 $('#menu').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide { 
 display:none
}
```

```html
<button>mouse over</button>
<div class='hide' id='menu'>Menu</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```